# How to get previous url, when the current page is open in new browser tab?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm setting up the back button using previous URL and redirect to previous page but when i copy the current page URL and it's open in the new browser tab but i can't access to the previous page through the current page. because the previous page URL was null.How to send the Previous URL When the current page open in new browser tab

I'm tring to get the previous URL using "this.$router.prevRoute" but it didn't work.Then i Use the method to get previous URL i provide that code below but i had same issue.

This is what I tried?

```php
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) 
{

next(vm => {
           vm.prevRoute = from;

        });
    }
```

URL is undefined.

Comment: are you using javascript?

Comment: How did you open new tab for the page? are you using Vue Router, vanilla js or html tag?

Comment: Yes. I'm using JS.

Comment: I'm coping the current page URL and it's open In the new tab. I'm using Vue Router.@Chris Chen

Answer (score 1):

Have you try pain JavaScript?

```js
alert(document.referrer)
```

Comment: Yes.I tried it But same thing happens. The URL is Null

Comment: May I ask which browser you are using?

Comment: Can you also provide the code for creating the link in new window?

Comment: Firefox and chrome.

Comment: In my test case in chrome, it works fine. Can you provide the code that open the link in new window?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this code.

```
Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')
//or
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

It will return the URL where it came from.

Comment: Some browsers or browser-addons will empty the referrer because of data protection reason

Answer (score -1):

You can use the History API.

```
window.history.back(); //Go to the previous page
window.history.forward(); //Go to the next page in the stack
window.history.go(index); //Where index could be 1, -1, 56, etc.
```

Comment: I tried it.but it's getting same issue ,Is their any methods to send the previous URL to the new browser tab.

Comment: did you try history.back?

Comment: Yes.I tried.When it open in the new tab the history will automatically erased.